# Cant start easytomcat7 on Centos

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, tomcat

When I pipe rpm -qa into the grep command I get this output

```
root@dar [/home]# rpm -qa | grep tomcat
easy-tomcat7-jsp-2.2-api-7.0.42-3.noarch
easy-tomcat7-admin-webapps-7.0.42-3.noarch
easy-tomcat7-7.0.42-3.noarch
easy-tomcat7-webapps-7.0.42-3.noarch
apache-tomcat-apis-0.1-1.el6.noarch
easy-tomcat7-lib-7.0.42-3.noarch
easy-tomcat7-javadoc-7.0.42-3.noarch
easy-tomcat7-docs-webapp-7.0.42-3.noarch
easy-tomcat7-el-2.2-api-7.0.42-3.noarch
easy-tomcat7-servlet-3.0-api-7.0.42-3.noarch
```

That's what I have inside the etc/init.d/tomcat

```
[/etc/init.d]# cat tomcat
#!/bin/bash
# description: Tomcat Syaty Stop Restart
# processname: tomcat
# chkconfig: 234 20 80 JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0`enter code here`_51 export
JAVA_HOME PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH export PATH
CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.26
case $1 in start) sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh;;stop) sh $
CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
;;
restart) sh
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sj 
;;
esac exit 0
```

How can I start/run the service?

Comment: Does catalina.out say anything?

Comment: yes it keeps loading too many processes. Example: [Loaded com.sun.xml.internal.stream.StaxXMLInputSource from /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.79.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.net.HttpURLConnection from /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.79.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLNotationDecl from /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.79.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar]